# Отправка сообщений определенным сокетам

Tags: java, сокет

Как можно отправлять сообщения не всем, а некоторым сокетам? Чтоб отправить всем, я делаю так:

```
listSocket = ListSocket.getListS(); 
for (Socket socket : listSocket) {
                            OutMessage = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                            OutMessage.println(InMessage);
                            OutMessage.flush();

                    }
```

Но никак не могу догадаться, как отправлять определенным сокетам, по некоторым схожими параметрами? Например, добавляется несколько пользователей с одинаковыми логинами. Можно ли их как-нибудь привязать к сокету и потом проводить проверку?
Сокеты храню в массиве.

Comment: @AlexSirk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Несколько пользователей с одинаковыми логинами? Это как? Сделайте им имя, что ли, уникальное. Определяйте юзера по имени или используйте ИП адрес. Далее положите всё в `HasmMap<String,Socket>`, где `String` - имя юзера или ИП адрес.

А потом создайте какой-нибудь метод, который ищет юзеров по определённым параметрам, например, регулярочка, извлекает подкарту и отправляет сообщения через эту подкарту.

Comment: А на сервере тоже Hashmap использовать?